# Can't access cookies in localhost even if httpOnly is false

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, localhost

as I wrote in the title of the question I can't access cookies in localhost.
I can see them from the developer tools  as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VA81.png)
and I can see the them from Express too if I print them, [like here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sXfA.png)
But, if I try to print the document.cookie an empty string is returned (as well as if I try to use other libraries).

I use React for the frontend and Express for backend.
React is hosted both in localhost at this URL: http://local.example.com/ and in remote at https://www.example.com/.
I can access the APIs at https://www.example.com/api.

I have no problems reading cookies in the remote React app while I can't in the local one.

React Fetch:

```
fetch(FETCH_URL + "/user/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 200){
            return response.json()
        }else{
            setError("Username or password are wrong")
        }
})
.then((data) => {
        if(data){ // Do stuff }
})
```

Express Cookies:

```
res.cookie("username", username, {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: true,
        domain: "",
        sameSite: "None"
})
res.cookie("token", token, {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        domain: "",
        sameSite: "None"
})
```

I know that I can't read from React the "token" cookie because it has the httpOnly flag true, but I expect to be able to read the "username" one (as I can with the remote React App).

I thought it could maybe happend because of the secure flag setted on true, but googling it seems that it should not affect the apps on localhost.

I took a look at many differen questions:
credentials-include, setting to an empty string the domain of the cookie, redirecting from local.example.com to 127.0.0.1 (hosts.ics), sameSite and secure attributes, fixing the cors policies of the backend, tried to set the domain to .example.com and the result is that I receive the cookies, they're saved in the browser, as I said, I can see them from the developer tools, as well from the backend, but I can't access them with JavaScript while I should be able to.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I actually needed to set-up **HTTPS for the local domain**.
I followed
[this](https://www.mariokandut.com/how-to-setup-https-ssl-in-localhost-react/) guide (it is for both windows and mac/linux and it was pretty quick too). Once done, my final npm-run script (for windows) is similar to the following: `set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE={PATH}&&set SSL_KEY_FILE={PATH}&&set HOST=local.example.com&&react-scripts start`
Hope it helps :D

Comment: hello, i m having same issue, my BE is on aws ec2 and my Frontend is on netlify, both servers has SSL certificate and i can see cookies on Dev tool, do you know what might cause the issue of not being able to get the cookie?

Comment: @JamalFakhriddinov does the cookie specify both a SameSite=None and Secure attribute?